# How to initialize Firebase in Xamarin Android project

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin

I am trying to integrate Google Firebase's Cloud Firestore into my cross-platform application which I am creating in Xamarin for Visual Studio. I am using the NuGet packages: `Plugin.CloudFirestore` and `Plugin.FirebaseAuth` in order to implement this. Everything seems to function properly for the iOS project; however, I cannot get it to work for the Android project. I get the following error whenever I try to make a call to Firebase:

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.companyname.appname. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Here is my `OnCreate` method in `MainActivity.cs`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        //----------Start of stuff I added----------
        Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);
        //----------End of stuff I added----------

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

I have also set the build action of my `google-services.json` to `GoogleServicesJson`. If anyone has any insight on what may be causing this problem that would be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: there are many existing questions about this problem - have you read them and tried their solutions?  https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+FirebaseApp.InitializeApp+site:stackoverflow.com